# Including column headers in CSV export from RDS postgres db using AWS Data Pipeline?

Tags: postgresql, csv, amazon-web-services

I set up an AWS data pipeline that dumps data from our RDS postgres db to a S3 location but the column headers are not included. I would like to avoid using the solution outlined [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/aws-pro-tip-export-data-from-rds-csv-format-using-pipelines-bejda) because it seems brittle (if the columns change, also want to avoid casting columns as string). Thanks in advance

ed.
Here is the data pipeline configuration: [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3LO6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how do you set the pipeline (you did not describe it), but the standard way of including column headers - with bare PostgreSQL - is

```
COPY (SELECT some,fields FROM any.table ORDER BY something) TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER on);
```

It might be tricky to receive such stream, not all DI tools support it - but the engine will generate it in proper CSV format.

Comment: Thanks for answering - unfortunately this didn't work in AWS: 'The driver currently does not support COPY operations.'

Comment: Right... I'm not experienced with AWS data pipelines. It might be possible to generate column headings using "Shell Command" component.

Comment: Data pipeline probably uses the JDBC driver, so unlikely to work in any case.  It certainly doesn't give you access to STDOUT, too high level.  This trick works well in shell scripts, though, just `TO /file/name.txt`.  Maybe just do the entire dump in a shell script and then read the file for the next step, if you can access it (?).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution for this either, but a possible workaround is to use a temporary destination folder for data-pipeline and use a Lambda function to take those dumps, add the headers, and move them to the final dest. The best of this approach is that the column names are not hard-coded, so if the table changes the CSV will change too.